# How to screen capture high-quality for printing for 300 DPI?

Tags: mac, printing, screen-capture

On the Mac I am aware of how to do a screen capture, but it creates a 72 DPI image. We need a much higher quality image because it's for printing on a color laser printer. We need to be able to print this out high-quality so it looks good on a 11 x 17 inch paper. Thanks!

Comment: It creates a 1:1 capture of your screen resolution.

Comment: Any way to improve the quality so it looks sharper when printed? Or is there another method than doing a screen capture? Kind of like Print to PDF, but Print to higher quality TIFF?

Answer (score 2):

Taken from [here](http://theturninggate.net/2012/08/change-screen-capture-file-format-on-mac-os-x/).

```
defaults write com.apple.screencapture type pdf
killall SystemUIServer
```

Several other choices besides pdf and default png, see link.

Comment: Can this also capture the entire screen, like from a web page even if it requires scrolling to see the entire web page?

Comment: You mean, with live scroll bars? No.

Answer (score 1):

If you run `sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.windowserver.plist DisplayResolutionEnabled -bool true` and restart, the Displays preference pane will include settings for HiDPI modes:

[image]

You can save a screenshot of an entire website with [webkit2png](http://www.paulhammond.org/webkit2png/):

```
brew install webkit2png
webkit2png -F http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/93321
```

`-F` only saves a full-size screenshot. webkit2png uses a HiDPI mode when a HiDPI resolution is selected from System Preferences.